# How do you measure and distinguish between E and D fields, and B and H fields

Tags: electromagnetism

I’m pretty familiar with maxwells equations, light waves, fields and materials etc, but I’m not clear on how the the various fields are actually measured. How is this typically done? Can the fields inside a material be directly measured?